# Lurie's applications of $\infty$-topoi in topology

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, cohomology, higher-category-theory, topos-theory

[Lurie's book](https://www.math.ias.edu/~lurie/papers/HTT.pdf) *Higher Topos Theory* is extremely interesting, but pretty overwhelming. I don't have the time to read it at the moment. However, the last chapter (7) gives *applications* of $\infty$-topoi in topology and I would like to know rough things about these applications - maybe somebody of you wants to give a summary. :-)

- In which way are $\infty$-topoi useful in topology? Just as a tool to *state* a theorem (elegantly) or as a tool to *prove* a theorem?
- If $\infty$-topoi are used to *prove* theorems, which theorems about $\infty$-topoi are used? (I am curious because I don't even know a proper application of *1-topoi* to topology.)
- The preface talks about how $\infty$-topoi solve the problem of understanding $H^n(X;G)$ for $n>1$ conceptually, similar to how $H^1(X;G)$ can be understood conceptually as being represented by the the classifying space $BG$, which classifies *$G$-torsors*. How do $\infty$-topoi help understanding $H^n(X;G)$ for $n>1$? How is that related to stacks? (I guess the preface is trying to explain exactly that - but I just don't understand what he is trying to say starting at page viii.)

What I find surprising: $\infty$-topoi seem to be useful for completely different things than 1-topoi. 1-topoi were invented to invent *étale cohomology*. But I don't see any $\infty$-étale cohomology in Lurie's book.

Comment: étale cohomology isn't much useful in topology - more in algebraic geometry. So a list of applications in topology wouldn't necessarily include generalizations of étale cohomology.

Comment: It's probably more in shape theory, which deals with the algebraic topology of spaces for which the usual invariants like homotopy groups and singular cohomology fail to detect nontrivial topology. If a topological space is so bad that there are no non-constant maps from standard simplices, then singular cohomology is trivial. Similarly if the topology is "too global" to detect with maps from boundaries of simplices (eg the Warsaw circle).